# Show page numbers in all pages of the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a memoir document that generates a toc that is over one page in length. The list of figures is also over one page in length. The problem is that those pages in the toc or the list of figures after the first page appear without page number.

I have tried every solution to every similar question on this site and yet nothing works. Is there anyone out there that knows how to fix this?

UPDATE:

Right now I have the following:

```
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{plain}
```

This fixes the numbering at the first and last pages of the toc, but the middle pages are still left without page number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you issuing a `\thispagestyle{empty}` anywhere? Perhaps you're using a template that is adding this to your `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` macros.

Comment: I am using \thispagestyle{empty} in several places but that would not explain why the first page of toc has a number and the pages after it do not :(

Comment: @JoseAlarcon: Yes it does, as the first page of every chapter (yes, the ToC is set as a special/starred `\chapter`) has a different page style, also set by `\thispagestyle`. Do you want the entire ToC/LoF/LoT to be void of a page style? That is, the entire `\frontmatter` should be set using `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @JoseAlarcon: I'm confused. Your post mentions "middle pages" while [your comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201535/show-page-numbers-in-all-pages-of-the-table-of-contents#comment469355_201535) mentions "[subsequent to the first]". Which is it?

Comment: Okay, so my table of contents is three pages in length. Using `\thispagestyle{plain}` before and after `\tableofcontents` puts a page number on the first and third page, but the second page is still without number.

By the way, what I want is roman numerals on the `\frontmatter`

Comment: I have tested with a very plain setup for `memoir` -- all ToC pages are numbered, as well as the LoF pages

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\frontmatter` fixed the problem. Now all pages in the ToC and LoF are numbered.